# linking sublimetext 2 to anaconda python mac os

Tags: python, sublimetext2, anaconda

I am looking for 2 hours now to find a guide to link my sublime text 2 editor to my anaconda python installation on mac os.

```
{ 
"path": "/Users/stephanketterer/anaconda/bin/", 
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"], 
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)", 
"selector": "source.python" 
}
```

I cannot find my mistake :(

Comment: What do you mean? It's an editor, you don't link it to anything. Write code with it, save it into a file `*.py` where `*` is a wildcard and run that file from the shell by typing python `*.py`.

Comment: @sobek are you familiar at all with Sublime? It has build systems that allow you to run and interact with code within the editor. Know what you're talking about before making snide comments next time.